# How to refresh page after change language in nextjs? Clientside to serverside

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next.js13

I am developing nextjs app. I get localized data by using query params ('website.com/data?lang=en'). So, when user change app locale, how can I refresh or trigger getServerSideProps (getStaticProps)? Or How to correctly detect locale change?

```
 // Client side change language
const changeLanguage = (locale) => {
  router.push(router.asPath, router.asPath, { locale });
};

const fetchData = async (locale) =>
  await client()
    .get('/api/products', { params: { lang: locale } })
    .then((res) => ({
      index: res.data
    }))
    .catch(() => ());

export const getServerSideProps = async (context) => {
  const { locale } = context;
  const data = await fetchData(locale);

  return {
    props: data,
    notFound
  };
};
export default Index;
```

Note: router.push not trigger serversideprops

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to do is reload the page you can you the browser `window.location.reload()` function.

Comment: I know that, but it is not good solution

Comment: Why is this not a good solution? It's exactly what you asked for.

Comment: It reload entire page, full reload